# Java- How to call Super Implementation method in subclass?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

How can i call super implementation in child class, if same method is overriden in Child class ??

`

```
// This interface is in different File

public Interface ParentClass {
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getName(firstName, LastName)  // How can i use this interface defined under getAllData     
}

// This method is in different File

public class ChildClass implements ParentClass {
public getAllData(fName, lName) { 
 ResponseEntity<byte[]> hObject = getName(fName, lName);    // this is calling below Overridden method. How to call super Implementation Interface here.
}

@Override
public getName(fName, lName) {  // This is getting called everytime during service call
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
// Before writing this Override method i was able to access Parent Interface
```

`

I can't remove Override method also.. Please help me.
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use super. e.g.
 super.getName(fName, lName);

Comment: question edited @Ashutosh - can you please check again once. Its interface parent

Comment: @A Emilia: Your interface does not have a default method implementation. So what is it supposed to do? 
If interface had a default implementation, you could have called like `ResponseEntity<byte[]> hObject = ParentClass.super.getName(fName, lName);`
But I guess this is not your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This method is in different File

public class ChildClass implements ParentClass {
public getAllData(fName, lName) { 
 return super.getName(fName, lName);    
}
```

Comment: getting error: 'The method getName(fName, lName) is undefined for the type Object'

Comment: so ChildClass is not child class of ParentClass. Exact code of the class header should be: public class ChildClass extends ParentClass

Comment: you can't use the `implements` keyword for classes in java

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa - right parent class is actually an interface for me. I edited my question.

Comment: @PetrF. Mistakenly i wrote method instead of interface. Sorry.. Your solution is perfect in case of methods but in my case its interface

Comment: Interface has not implemented methods, so you cant call method of interface.